# Rendering options in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Can someone explain to me what is happening with my render?
Everything is okay when I render in EVEE, but when I render it in Cycles, these mystery lines appear in some of the images.
By the way, I'm trying to render animation :D

[image: Cycles Render]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com